# C# array-like data embedded in a struct

Tags: c#, unsafe

Im building an ECS, and need to be able to store a large array of structs containing data contigousy in memory, as the point of the ECS is to make good use of cache lines.

I want one type of struct to have a collection inside of it.

The default behaviour of a struct would be

```
struct BadStruct
{
    int[] data = int[64];
}
```

Would allocate the array somewhere else on the heap and all the good data locaity would be lost.

I am slightly aware of the unsafe

```
unsafe struct UnsafeStruct
{
    public fixed int data[64];      
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is gurentted to embed the array in my array of structs.

Is there a better way to acheive what I want? And are there any pitfalls with using fixed buffers like this?

Comment: I believe fixed-sized buffers really *are* exactly what you want, so I wouldn't expect there to be a "better way".

Comment: What's an ECS? Another alternative is to have a struct with 64 int members (not a good alternative, but an alternative).

Comment: Considering the concern of the question about "ECS" making good use of cache-lines, i would assume ECS here stands for [Entity Component System](https://github.com/SanderMertens/ecs-faq). But it is better for OP to confirm what they actually refer to as ECS...

Comment: @Flydog57 sorry yes, ECS: Entity Ccomponent System

Comment: It looks like the link @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace posted has some good examples of ECS in C# that might be worth studying. In general I'd think that either allocating a large array on the heap and dealing with occasional relocations (If it's big enough and winds up on LOH, it may never be compacted i.e. moved depending on running environment!), or consider dotNext's [Unmanaged memory pool](https://github.com/dotnet/dotNext/tree/master/src/DotNext.Unsafe/Buffers) as it may be useful if you are thinking of rolling your own.

Comment: An array/memory pool might be a good idea, there are already classes for it in the framework.

Comment: I literally pushed my c# archetype based ecs a few days ago, might wanna check it out for ideas or even contribute to it : https://github.com/genaray/Arch

Gonna get a "huge" update soon with bulk adding, removing. Pooled collections, source code generator for efficient querys and even continous chunk arrays which makes unmanaged structs even faster to iterate over.